# Will Ukraine let me in if they see I've been in Russia first?

Tags: visas, russia, ukraine

I am planning a trip through Russia so I have to get the visa in my own country (Australia). But then I plan to go to Ukraine and I can get a visa upon arrival (if under 15 days). Is there  any risk that they would not allow me in? I'm just a tourist although I am of Ukrainian background and have relatives in Ukraine that I will be visiting.

Comment: Are you planning travel to Crimea?

Answer (score 11):

There is no risk. Even Russian citizens are allowed to visit Ukraine, so why would somebody who has visited Russia be not allowed to enter the country?..

Comment: In addition, even citizens of Ukraine get to travel to Russia. Citizens of both countries can visit each other for 90 days visa free. So yeah, no risk as Neusser said!

Answer (score 4):

Ukraine doesn't practice prohibiting people who have ever visited any other country entrance to its territory.

The only thing you should keep in mind is that if you'll during your visit to Russian Federation enter the occupied territories, such as the Crimean peninsula or part of Donbas behind so-called separation line from the Russian territory, it'll be considered an illegal border crossing and then you'll be either denied entrance to Ukraine or arrested.

Comment: And how would they know you've been to Crimea unless you try to cross from Crimea into Ukraine? I say there's nothing to worry about at all

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely go to Ukraine after Russia, don't worry.

Note that [visa upon arrival only](http://australia.mfa.gov.ua/en/consular-affairs/services/Visa+to+Ukraine) for Australians exists at Ukrainian **airports only**, and not at the land borders, and that you need to fulfil the requirements for the visa-on-arrival.

Were you to get a visa before arriving to Ukraine, you could cross (to my repeated experience efficiently and hazel-free) overland from Russia. Do, however, stay clear of the Donbass and Crimea to which the dispute has had some [profound implications for travellers](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/eastern-europe/travel-tips-and-articles/crimea-under-russian-rule-what-has-changed-for-travellers/40625c8c-8a11-5710-a052-1479d2766e30).

Comment: Thanks. I also read on the Australian Department of Foreign Affairs website that "Children born in Australia to a Ukrainian parent are considered citizens of Ukraine by the Ukrainian Government. Anecdotal evidence suggests that tourist visas won't be granted to Australian citizens born in Ukraine or to Ukrainian parents." Have you ever heard of this happening?

Comment: @Lydia that is correct, but you'll need a proof of citizenship, e.g. passport of the national identity card.

Comment: Oh. Quite right. Maybe a separate question regarding tourist visas for descendants of Ukrainians citizens is in order?